# Does IE have anything similar to what -moz-border-radius does in firefox/chrome?

Tags: css

Does IE have anything similar to what -moz-border-radius does in firefox/chrome?

Also is the -moz-border-radius supported by safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE doesn't support the border radius CSS3 or custom implementations.  Your best bet is to use something like jQuery and a rounded corners plug in (see below) to accomplish it.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/corners

Here's a 2nd plug in that I use more often than the above:

http://www.methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner-demo.html

EDIT:
As for safari, yes it has a custom implementation like mozilla.

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px; /* mozilla */
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* safari */
```

Comment: I also tried this library, and believe this one was REALLY broken in IE variants.

Comment: For the safari version, how do I switch between the 2?  OR would I just set them both in a stylesheet and the proper browser will ignore the other version?

Comment: @jasondavis safari and IE will ignore the -moz prefix items when parsing the css so you would do both and you'll be set.

Comment: @iftrue I use the 2nd library more often than the first link I provided.  I have seen a few issues in IE6 when I use CSS frameworks like BluePrintCSS or 960 Grids but other than that, I haven't seen too many issues.

Answer (score 1):

I tried corners last week, and it was broken in a number of browsers, most notably IE8. I'd avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should design your design so that it looks and works ok in IE, and if opened in one of the newer browsers little things like rounded corners would just make your site look that much better.  Things like that will eventually cause users to move to newer browsers, when the experience is better in one and not the other.

Comment: That's what we do 'round these parts.  IE gets crappy hard corners.